# Match with multiple arrays

Tags: javascript

I start with multiple arrays. Then based on the checkbox selection I would like to crosscheck the value with the `item` array and get the relevant values from the `price` and `exp` arrays.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="grocery" value="peach">
<input type="checkbox" name="grocery" value="apple">
<input type="checkbox" name="grocery" value="orange">
```

example if the 2nd check box is checked (value="apple") then I need to be able to get its values separately.

This is what I have so far. How do I match the selected checkbox values to the `item` array to be able to gather the values from the `price`, `exp` and `lot` arrays? I am looking for a way to do it in vanilla javascript.

```
let item = ["peach", "apple", "orange"];
let price = [21, 32, 18];
let exp = [21, 18, 25];
let lot = [6, 8, 4];
let crossCheck = [];

let items = document.getElementsByName('grocery');
for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if(items[i].type == 'checkbox' && items[i].checked) {
        crossCheck.push(items[i].value);
        console.log(s)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be storing these values in different arrays. Relying on array index will bite you when the codebase grows and different functions will want to access these values. Just use an object -

```
{
 "apple": {
       "price":32,
       "lot":8
  }
}
```

This way, when you want to access the price and lot of apple you can just do `apple.price` or `apple.lot` without convoluted iteration or for loops

-- EDIT 1

Getting list of checked elements.

```
let inputElements = document.getElementsByName("grocery"); 
let checked = [...inputElements].map(item => { 
  if(item.checked) { 
     return item.value 
  }
}).filter(item => item); 
console.log(checked)
```

1. You get all elements by name.
2. You convert the list of DOM elements into an array using spread syntax `[...inputElements]`
3. Then you iterate over that array, check for "checked" status and if true return the value. If it's not true, you will get undefined in that location.
4. Then you filter over the resulting checked array to remove "undefined" elements.

I encourage you to console.log each statement line by line.

After that you check for what values have been selected and extract that from `const Items = { apple:{ price:32, lot:8}}`. If you will only be allowing for one of the fruits to be checked then you can pretty much do `Items[checked[0]].price` to get the price and `Items[checked[0]].lot` to get the lot.

If you allow for multiple checked input values, then you have to iterate over all the values using map or forEach.

Comment: Interesting... So everything is in one array? `let myArray = [{"peach": {"price":32,"lot":8}}, {"apple": {"price":21,"lot":6}},....]` ?

Comment: Precisely. If you do not have a large list of elements, then I'd keep it in a single object like `{
 "apple": {
       "price":32,
       "lot":8
  },
"peach":{"price":18,"lot":7"} ....
}`

Comment: There will be around 15 `items`. Currently I do `for(var i=0; i<items.length; i++){` and then crosscheck. If I follow this approach, how should the cross checking be done?

Comment: You just fetch value by key. If you know you want to fetch price and lot of apple from `const Items = { apple:{ price:32, lot:8}}` then you do `Items.apple`. For apple's price you do `Items.apple.price`. This makes the code easier to read.

Comment: I'll give it a try now.

Comment: I'm not doing it right. `var items=document.getElementsByName('grocery');
        for(var i=0; i<items.length; i++){
          if(items[i].type=='checkbox' && items[i].checked==true){
            console.log( array.items[i].value.lot );
          }
        }`

Answer (score 2):

The best way I think you using the array of object.

```
let array = [
    { "item": "peach", "price": 21, "exp": 21, "lot": 6 },
    { "item": "apple", "price": 32, "exp": 18, "lot": 8 },
    { "item": "orange", "price": 18, "exp": 25, "lot": 4 }
]
```

after define you can add to `crossCheck`

```
crossCheck.push(array[i])
```

Hope this solution can help you.
Thanks for reading

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. +10

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array.reduce` to map items with your their respective fields like so,
I am assuming your item names are unique.

```js
let items = ["peach", "apple", "orange"];
let price = [21, 32, 18];
let exp = [21, 18, 25];
let lot = [6, 8, 4];
let crossCheck = [];

const itemMap = items.reduce((map, item, index)=>{
  map[item] = [price[index], exp[index], lot[index]];
  return map;
},{});

document.getElementsByName('grocery').forEach((item, index) => {
  if(item.type=='checkbox' && item.checked==true){
       crossCheck.push(item.value);
  }
});

crossCheck.forEach(item => {
  console.log(`${item} price is ${itemMap[item][0]}`);
  console.log(`${item} exp is ${itemMap[item][1]}`);
  console.log(`${item} lot is ${itemMap[item][2]}`);
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="grocery" value="peach">
<input type="checkbox" name="grocery" value="apple" checked>
<input type="checkbox" name="grocery" value="orange">
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, use addEventListener and using index of for loop with let **i** variable

1. Loop items using for loop with let to get each loop index value
2. Add addEventListener with on change event
3. On every check, push to crossCheck array

```js
let item = ["peach", "apple", "orange"];
let price = [21, 32, 18];
let exp = [21, 18, 25];
let lot = [6, 8, 4];
let crossCheck = [];

let items = document.getElementsByName('grocery');
for(let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    items[i].addEventListener('change', function() {
    if(this.checked) {
        crossCheck.push({item: item[i], price: price[i], exp: exp[i], lot: lot[i]})
    }
      console.log(crossCheck)
    });
}
```

```html
Peach <input type="checkbox" name="grocery" value="peach">
Apple <input type="checkbox" name="grocery" value="apple">
Orange <input type="checkbox" name="grocery" value="orange">
```

codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/gJWaxE